# How to trigger "updated" event of a service from another service

Tags: feathersjs

I've got two services in Feathers. 
For the sake of example, let's call them:

1. TodoLists
2. TodoItems

TodoItems have a N:1 association to TodoLists, and I *include* the TodoItems model in a find hook of the TodoLists service.

Now - on my frontend I have a listener that listens for 'update' event on TodoLists.

What is the right way to get the 'update' event emitted for TodoLists when any *TodoItem* is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try watching on all TodoItems updates and filter by your TodoList id.

```js
const currentTodoList = 1;
app.service('TodoItems').on('updated', (item) => {
  if (item.todolist === currentTodoList){
    // update ui
  }
});
```

If you additionally want to optimize the traffic send by the backend to only send needed data, you could use some subscribe pattern (TodoListSubscription join feathers channel in create and leave in remove).

Comment: Thanks for answering.
This would do the job but seems to be more of a workaround - it wouldn't actually trigger the 'update' event of the TodoLists service. Do you know of any way to trigger the event and send to all listeners their respective data? I have to admit I don't really understand how Feathers holds account of what queries are to be updated how...

Comment: Okay sorry, I was confused since I have a caching service on the client. I think now your answer is the way to go. Thanks!